# How to return the string prefix from regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a group of strings and I'm trying to remove everything after and including the last occurance of a regexp match.

```
Sample Data
23401BK221
23430-BZ-221
1004113-BK-3
14989r-113
30402113
```

I am attempting to do this with

```
extensions_to_remove="BK|BZ|113"
sample_data = sample_data.split(/.*(#{extensions_to_remove}$1)/)
```

I was hoping that I would get an array where I could just take the first entry, but unfortunately, I'm getting

```
["","BK", "-221"]
["","BZ","-221"]
["","BK", "-3"]
["","113"]
["", "113"]
```

What I'm hoping to get is

```
23401
23430
1004113
14989r
30402
```

So essentially remove everthing after the last match, and then if their is a trailing '-' I'm trying to remove that.

I figured if I got it into an array, I could take the first value, then strip the trailing '-', if it existed.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Why I'm not getting the prefixes back?
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your question is badly stated. What is "the last occurance of a regexp"? What do you mean by "take the first entry"? Why do you expect "30402" instead of "30402113" in the last string? What do you mean by "last match"

Comment: @sawa - you are right about the 'last occurance of a regexp', updating that. The 'first entry' of an array is array[0], what would you call it. The 'last match' is the last occurance of the matched string. I expect 30402 instead of 30402113 because I'm attempting to remove 113 from the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
(\w+).*(BK|BZ|113)
```

Code:

```
data = ["23401BK221", "23430-BZ-221", "1004113-BK-3", "14989r-113", "30402113"]
data.each {|d| p d.split(/(\w+).*(BK|BZ|113)/)[1]}
```

Output:

```
gazler@gazler-desktop:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p180 (2011-02-18 revision 30909) [x86_64-linux]
gazler@gazler-desktop:~$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > data = ["23401BK221", "23430-BZ-221", "1004113-BK-3", "14989r-113", "30402113"]
 => ["23401BK221", "23430-BZ-221", "1004113-BK-3", "14989r-113", "30402113"] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > data.each {|d| p d.split(/(\w+).*(BK|BZ|113)/)[1]}
"23401"
"23430"
"1004113"
"14989r"
"30402"
```

Rubular link: http://rubular.com/r/kKrseNE7ZX

Comment: I'm sure that is incredibly close, unfortunately, this is splitting on each occurance, and than taking the first split. I'm looking to split on the last occurance. In your rubular example, it works perfectly, but then in ruby, for 1004113-BK-3, I'm getting 1004, rather than 1004113.

Comment: Rubular runs on ruby, so the error you are getting is odd,  Which version of ruby are you on?  Try /(\w+)-?(BK|BZ|113)/ instead.

Comment: Rubular is running ruby, but you don't have a 'split' statement in rubular. I'm thinking that is causing the problem. Is there another way to run a straight regexp against a string and get a result? Your second update is returning the same result. I'm on Ruby 1.92

Comment: Strange, I am on 1.9.2 and it is working here.  You can use match instead of split.  Are you running the code from my answer?  I have provided my console output if it helps.

Comment: yeah, something strange here, but I'm sure it is on my side. I'm trying to test edge cases, but the core is working just as you've got it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you really want to ensure it is working, you could try reversing the string and then matching the reverse of the regex (KB|ZB|311)-? and capturing everything AFTER that.

Answer (score 2):

In one step without using `split`.

```
sample_data = %w[
  23401BK221
  23430-BZ-221
  1004113-BK-3
  14989r-113
  30402113
]
sample_data = sample_data.map{|s| s[/(.*[^-])-?(?:BK|BZ|113)/, 1]}
```

Comment: nice, though I already awarded the answer to Gazler. You say that this isn't using the 'split', and you correct in that it isn't using the word 'split', but in the backgroud, isn't this still splitting the string into an array and then taking the first? Performance wise,I'm not going to se any benefit am I?

Comment: It's not splitting it into an array. The irrelevant parts are not captured, so it is probably better performance wise. I know you already dicided the answer. No problem.