# Return prefix of string using regular expression where stripped string sometimes contains '/'

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to return a prefix of a string, my related question is here,but I've run into a new problem.

[How to return the string prefix from regexp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129413/how-to-return-the-string-prefix-from-regexp)

Basically I have a strings like

```
23430-BL
23430BZ
23430BK/BL
```

The Extensions I'm trying to remove are

```
strip_ext = BK/BL|BZ|BL
```

The regular expression I'm using to get the string without the extension is

```
prefix = sample_data[/(.*[^-])-?(?:#{strip_ext})/,1]
```

This is returning

```
23430
23430
23430-BK
```

In theory, I understand that the regexp finds the BL match, and for some reason selects that as the match over the BK/BL. But is there a way to get the regexp to find BK/BL rather than BL?

Unfortunately, there isn't always a dash before the part that I am looking to strip.

I added the original strip_ext list as an example, and thought it would make it easy to understand. An actual strip_ext list looks like this and changes based on the sample data provided, so unfortunately it isn't as easy as Mu's answer below.

```
AM/DB|AM/BN|RD/BK|PR/WT|YP/BN|YP/CH|YP/DB|PK/BN|PK/CH|PK/DB|SF/BN|SF/CH|SF/DB|AM/CH|BN/CH|BN/DB|CH/BN|CH/DB|DB/BN|DB/CH|BN/BN|CH/CH|MR/BN|MR/CH|MR/DB|DB/DB|AM/AB|DIC/BN|DIC/CH|DIC/DB|BN|DB|WT|BN/WT|BK|WT/BN|BK/BN|BK/DB|BL/BN|BL/DB|BK/CH|BL/CH|AM|CH|FR|SB|AM/BK|AM/WT|PT/CH|BG/CH|BG/DB|MF/CH|MF/DB|YR/CH|YR/DB|WT/DB|pt/bn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the first quantifier ungreedy.

```
(.*?[^-])-?(?:BK/BL|BZ|BL)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2umu0)

The `?` causes the `.*?` to match as less as possible.

Comment: WOW! I was wondering why it wasn't being greedy like a treetop parser. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could mix a negative look-behind into your `BL` matcher:

```
/(.*[^-])-?(?:BK\/BL|BZ|(?<!BK\/)BL)/
```

Adding `(?<!BK\/)` indicates that you want to match `BL` except when it is preceded by `BK/`.

A quick test:

```
>> %w{23430-BL 23430GR 23430BK/BL}.map { |s| s[/(.*[^-])-?(?:BK\/BL|BZ|(?<!BK\/)BL)/,1] }
=> ["23430", nil, "23430"]
```

Your sample output doesn't match your input though, is "GR" a typo in your inputs or is "BZ" a typo in your regex?

---

Given that your patterns are not fixed, you could bypass regular expressions completely and fall back on simple string wrangling. Here's a better example of what I mentioned in my comment:

```
require 'set'

# The suffix list that you get from somewhere.
suffixes  = [ 'BK/BL', 'BZ', 'BL' ]

# We want to do a couple things at once here. For each suffix, we
# want both the suffix and the suffix with a leading '-' attached,
# the `map` and `flatten` stuff does that. Then we group them by
# length to get a hash like:
#
#     { 2 => ['BZ','BL'], 3 => ['-BZ', '-BL'], 5 => ['BK/BL'], ... }
#
by_length = suffixes.map { |suffix| [suffix, '-' + suffix ] }.flatten.group_by(&:length)

# Now we reorganize our suffixes into sets with the set of longest
# suffixes first and the set of shortest suffixes last. The result
# will be:
#
#     [#<Set: {"-BK/BL"}>, #<Set: {"BK/BL"}>, #<Set: {"-BZ", "-BL"}>, #<Set: {"BZ", "BL"}>]
#
sets = by_length.keys.sort { |a,b| b <=> a }.map { |k| Set.new(by_length[k]) }

# Then we can just spin through sets, pull off the suffix of the
# appropriate length from the string, and see if it is in our set.
# If it is then chop the suffix off the string, do whatever is to be
# done with chopped string, and break out for the next string.
#
%w{ 23430-BL 23430BZ 23430BK/BL }.each do |string|
    sets.each do |suffixes|
        len = suffixes.first.length
        sfx = string[string.length - len, len]
        if(suffixes.include?(sfx))
            puts string[0 .. -(len + 1)]
            break
        end
    end
end
```

That's just an "off the top of my head" illustration of the algorithm.

Comment: Thanks mu, I fixed the error in the sample data. Unfortunately, I am programatically getting the list of extensions that need to be striped, as it changes depending on different lists of input data. I was just providing a subset here. I don't think I can programatically write the look-behind as it would be a huge tasks to find all the strip_exts that may require a look behind. I've added an actual strip_ext list in the question, to give an idea of the data I'm actually dealing with. Thanks for the look-behind info though, I'm sure that will come in handy another time.

Comment: @pedalpete: You could group your suffixes by length, throw them into sets (one for each length), then for each string pull off the suffix of length 4 and set if it is in the set of length 4 suffixes, then try length 3, and work your way down from the longest possible suffixes to the shortest. Basically ditch regexes completely and go with simple string operations. Regexes are good tools but there are other tools.

Comment: @pedalpete: I added an update with a non-regex approach if you're interested.

Comment: thanks for the help, and originally I was looking at a non-regex way of doing this, so all your work may come in handy in the future. Thanks for going through the trouble. Stema's answer is obviously more in line with what I'm going for.

Comment: @pedalpete: So it was the `.*`? I habitually use `.*?` so I missed the completely :)